# Multisocket - how to count how many datagram packets are coming up

Tags: java

So I am sending audio over UDP via multicast.
And the sender is sending a raw audio UDP packet every 10 ms. Unfortunately every now and then it misses a packet. So what I did was try to time the send/receive so that I can work out if I have missed one.

Here is what I currently have:

```
prevReceived = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    socket.receive(recv);
                    long messageReceived = System.currentTimeMillis();
if (dateDiff > 20) {
 ... Missed packet add the previous packet
```

The problem that I am having is that sometimes the java multisocket receive method is taking 70ms to receive a message. But when I check with Microsoft network monitor the sending is still sending messages.

So I was wondering if there is a way to look at if the multisocket object has any pending packets: socket.count() or something.
or does the datagrampacket received time from the socket time. eg something like recv.timestamp().

So far I have not found anything and cannot work out why it is taking 70ms to process the message when Microsoft network monitor is processing it every 10 ms.

Answer (score 0):

Apache mina can count your datagram packets.

http://mina.apache.org/mina/userguide/ch2-basics/sample-udp-server.html

http://mina.apache.org/mina/userguide/user-guide-toc.html